# Best way to find previous and next elements in a list

Tags: python, list, element, items

What is the efficient way to find the previous and next elements based on a given element index?

```
list = [(100, 112), (100, 100), (200, 100), (200, 125), (240, 130), (240, 100), (272, 100)]
idx = 2 # for example
print('Next elements are', list[idx + 1:] )
```

***Correct output***

> Next elements are [(200, 125), (240, 130), (240, 100), (272, 100)]

while this line prints wrong elements:

```
print ('Prev elements are', list[idx - 1:])
```

***Wrong output***

> [(100, 100), (200, 100), (200, 125), (240, 130), (240, 100), (272, 100)]

Why this is happening? I tried this too `list[(idx-1)%len(list):]`

Comment: Have you tried `print ('Prev elements are', list[:idx])`? Note the heading `:` not trailing

Comment: If you want the next elements, why are you subtracting 1? Use `list[idx+1:]`

Comment: Also, don't call your objects `list` because that tramples the built-in type

Comment: @Chris I never thought about that. Works perfectly.I did a lot of googling still didn't find this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Take a look at the linked answer. It would be a good start for understanding slicing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have array like this:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and index defined:

```
index = 4
```

**Elements before:**

```
print(arr[:index])
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Elements after:**

```
print(arr[index+1:])
> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

PS: If your index is in `range(0, len(arr)-2)` then you are going to get after elements, otherwise you will get `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression for the previous elements would be

`print ('Prev elements are', list[:idx])`

Also, small note, don't name your lists `list` as `list` is a reserved name in Python, used as the name of the language-provided `list` type!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that naming error. Actual name is different. While editing and simplifying question I accidentally named it as list.